# Scale objects together but not from a common center

Tags: faces

I am trying to select multiple faces and modify them together. I ideally want it to look like this (just more symmetrical).
[image]

However, when I select all the faces and scale them, they all scale from the center of all of the objects, like this:

[image]

Is there a way that I can select all these faces and scale them relative to where they are so I can make it look more like the first photo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enable *Transform Pivot Point > Individual Origins*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Manual here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/individual_origins.html#individual-origins)

Comment: @moonboots you are too fast. By the time I was done with the gif your answer was up!

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there had to be some place that I was missing!!

Comment: sorry Susu  ;)  and thanks for the edit